# Stanford CoreNLP old versions

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP to explore the SQuAD 2.0 dataset. When using the constituency parsing of the latest version 3.9.2, I found this sentence returned as NP-rooted:

"Carolina 's secondary featured Pro Bowl safety Kurt Coleman, who led the team with a career high seven interceptions, while also racking up 88 tackles and Pro Bowl cornerback Josh Norman, who developed into a shutdown corner during the season and had four interceptions, two of which were returned for touchdowns."

But it is returned as S-rooted in this demo site (seems to be the 2016-9-12 version):

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

I found more than one sentence with the same situation. The site cannot be connected now. My question is:

What is the difference between these two versions? Is it possible to find the older version?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to experiment with older versions of the code and different models, you can find resources here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html